# How to retrieve the serialized object from Hazelcast's Imap?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, hazelcast

The below code is for putting a kryo serialised object into an Hazelcast's Imap instance followed by retrieving. On retrieving the object it throws an error named:

> com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

My code is given below.

```
package hazelcast2;

import java.util.Scanner;

import com.hazelcast.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.hazelcast.config.Config;
import com.hazelcast.config.InMemoryFormat;
import com.hazelcast.config.MapConfig;
import com.hazelcast.config.SerializerConfig;
import com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast;
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;
import com.hazelcast.core.IMap;
import com.hazelcast.core.ISet;


public class zlibtry {
    public static Config config;
    public static ClientConfig cfg;
    public static HazelcastInstance hz;
    public static IMap<String,MyDataObject> mapItemCount; 
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
//      Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        config= new Config();
    
        config.setProperty("hazelcast.elastic.memory.enabled" , "true");
        config.setProperty("hazelcast.elastic.memory.total.size", "60G");
        config.setProperty("hazelcast.elastic.memory.chunk.size","2");
        MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig();
        mapConfig.setInMemoryFormat( InMemoryFormat.OBJECT );
        //config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5701);
        //config.getNetworkConfig().setPublicAddress("127.0.0.1"); 
        config.setProperty("address","127.0.0.1");
        
        SerializerConfig productSerializer = new SerializerConfig()
         .setTypeClass(MyDataObject.class).setImplementation(new ProductKryoSerializer(true));
        config.getSerializationConfig().addSerializerConfig(productSerializer);

        hz=Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);

         mapItemCount=hz.getMap("objectMap");
         
         MyDataObject obj = new MyDataObject();
         
         ISet<Integer> iset = hz.getSet("zlibset2");
         iset.add(1);
         
         obj.setMyList(iset);
         
         mapItemCount.put("1", obj);
         
         System.out.println(mapItemCount.get("1").getMyList().toString());
         
         
         
         
         
    }   
}
```

The below code is for productKyroSerializer:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream;

import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output;
import com.hazelcast.nio.ObjectDataInput;
import com.hazelcast.nio.ObjectDataOutput;
import com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializer;

public class ProductKryoSerializer implements StreamSerializer {
    private final boolean compress;

    private static final ThreadLocal<Kryo> kryoThreadLocal 
           = new ThreadLocal<Kryo>() {
        
        @Override
        protected Kryo initialValue() {
            Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
            kryo.register(MyDataObject.class);
            return kryo;
        }
    };

    public ProductKryoSerializer(boolean compress) {
        this.compress = compress;
    }

    public int getTypeId() {
        return 2;
    }

    public void write(ObjectDataOutput objectDataOutput, MyDataObject product) 
           throws IOException {
        Kryo kryo = kryoThreadLocal.get();

        if (compress) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = 
                new ByteArrayOutputStream(16384);
            DeflaterOutputStream deflaterOutputStream = 
                new DeflaterOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
            Output output = new Output(deflaterOutputStream);
            kryo.writeObject(output, product);
            output.close();

            byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            objectDataOutput.write(bytes);
        } else {
            Output output = new Output((OutputStream) objectDataOutput);
            kryo.writeObject(output, product);
            output.flush();
        }
    }

    public MyDataObject read(ObjectDataInput objectDataInput) 
           throws IOException {
        InputStream in = (InputStream) objectDataInput;
        if (compress) {
            in = new InflaterInputStream(in);
        }
        Input input = new Input(in);
        Kryo kryo = kryoThreadLocal.get();
        return kryo.readObject(input, MyDataObject.class);
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

//  @Override
//  public Object read(ObjectDataInput arg0) throws IOException {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      return null;
//  }

    public void write(ObjectDataOutput arg0, Object arg1) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
}
```

And moreover, I think there should be some proper method to retrieve the object after deserialisation.

You can see the "objectMap" hazelcast's IMap instance and I have updated some code in hazelcast.xml:

```
<map name="objectMap">
    <in-memory-format>OBJECT</in-memory-format>
</map>

<map name="cachedMap">
    <in-memory-format>CACHED</in-memory-format>
</map>

<map name="binaryMap">
    <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
</map>
```

and the code for myDataObject is

```
import com.hazelcast.core.IList;
import com.hazelcast.core.ISet;

public class MyDataObject {
ISet<Integer> myList;

public ISet<Integer> getMyList() {
    return myList;
}

public void setMyList(ISet<Integer> myList) {
    this.myList = myList;
}

}
```

Comment: I guess without the serializer code there is no chance to even guess a reason :)

Comment: i have updated as per your request @noctarius, moreover i think there should be some extra method/class to retrieve the serialised object. please help!!!

Comment: Oh haven't seen it earlier but an ISet is not serializable and therefore you can't use it as a field. See the following answer.

Answer (score 2):

ISet is not serializable and cannot be serialized directly as a field inside of a class. See the following snippet for a possible solution.

```
public class MyDataObject
    implements KryoSerializable, HazelcastInstanceAware {

  private ISet<Integer> myList;
  private String myListName;

  public ISet<Integer> getMyList() {
    return myList;
  }

  public void setMyList(ISet<Integer> myList) {
    this.myList = myList;
    this.myListName = myList.getName();
  }

  public void write (Kryo kryo, Output output) {
    output.writeString(myListName);
  }

  public void read (Kryo kryo, Input input) {
    this.myListName = input.readString();
  }

  public void setHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
    this.myList = hazelcastInstance.getSet(myListName);
  }
}
```

I guess that should work (at least kind of ;-)) just wrote it in the browser.

Comment: the code you have given me is not working. Moreover, i have already implemented, this in my KryoProductSerialer class. Have a look at it. My main motive is to insert an ISet into an IMap. suggest some methods.

Comment: There is no way to do it, as I already said. You can only do tricks. No idea what you mean by "doesn't work", a bit more detail might render pretty useful.

Comment: No, I have already implemented this in my Kryo serialiser. The code for that is given above. One thing I recently found is, when I insert using Kryo serialiser, the map size is updated, but it is actually a null value. So, tell me other possibilities. 1) using multi map, as it promises it can accept non-serialise object. 2) i have got the source code for hazelcast package. Change something in the code so that i include my own serialised implementation of map. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "1) using multi map, as it promises it can accept non-serialise object." what does that mean? If it means what I think this is very wrong :)